Laravel CRUD application returning null for individual items
I am trying to make a Laravel crud application following a tutorial but unable to get my items to show with data individually. I can output all items in the database but unable to output a single item with postman. Hoping someone can help me figure this out, thank you.
In postman, this outputs all the data correctly
http://localhost:8000/api/orders/
However, when I try to look at an individual item, it returns all null for any item ID
http://localhost:8000/api/orders/1 results in null data
http://localhost:8000/api/orders/2 results in null data
http://localhost:8000/api/orders/3 results in null data
etc
output postman http://localhost:8000/api/orders/

"data": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "details": "CREDIT\n",
            "posting_date": "2023-10-05",
            "description": "Online Transfer from CHK ...8760 transaction#: 18639\n",
            "amount": "950.00",
            "type": "ACCT_XFER\n",
            "balance": "2468.81",
            "check_or_slip": "",
            "category": "Rent",
            "property": "",
            "notes": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "details": "DEBIT\n",
            "posting_date": "2023-09-05",
            "description": "Online Transfer to CHK ...8760 transaction#: 18362 09/05\n",
            "amount": "-1050.00",
            "type": "ACCT_XFER\n",
            "balance": "1518.81",
            "check_or_slip": "",
            "category": "",
            "property": "",
            "notes": ""
        },

output postman http://localhost:8000/api/orders/3
{
    "data": {
        "id": null,
        "details": null,
        "posting_date": null,
        "description": null,
        "amount": null,
        "type": null,
        "balance": null,
        "check_or_slip": null,
        "category": null,
        "property": null,
        "notes": null
    }
}

I have 4 files which I have created with the tutorial but changed it to fit my use.
routes-> api.php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Api\PurchaseOrdersController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\AuthController;



Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {

    Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::get('/profile', [AuthController::class, 'profile']);
});

Route::apiResource('orders', PurchaseOrdersController::class);

Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->middleware('auth:sanctum');

Models -> Orders.php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Orders extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'accounting';

    protected $fillable =[
        'details',
        'posting_date',
        'description',
        'amount',
        'type',
        'balance',
        'check_or_slip',
        'category',
        'property',
        'notes'
    ];
}

Resources -> OrderResource.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class OrderResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'details' => $this->details,
            'posting_date' => $this->posting_date,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'amount' => $this->amount,
            'type' => $this->type,
            'balance' => $this->balance,
            'check_or_slip' => $this->check_or_slip,
            'category' => $this->category,
            'property' => $this->property,
            'notes' => $this->notes
        ];
    }
}


App->http->Controllers->Api->PurchaseOrdersController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Models\Orders;
use App\Http\Resources\OrderResource;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PurchaseOrdersController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $orders = Orders::get();
        if ($orders->count() > 0) {
            return OrderResource::collection($orders);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'No record available'], 200);
        }
    }

    //add to database
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'details' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'posting_date' => 'string|max:255',
            'description' => 'string|max:255',
            'amount' => 'decimal:2',
            'type' => 'string|max:255',
            'balance' => 'decimal:2',
            'check_or_slip' => 'string|max:255',
            'category' => 'string|max:255',
            'property' => 'string|max:255',
            'notes' => 'string|max:255',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'All fields are mandatory',
                'error' => $validator->messages(),
            ], 422);
        }

        $orders = Orders::create([
            'details' => $request->details,
            'posting_date' => $request->posting_date,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'amount' => $request->amount,
            'type' => $request->type,
            'balance' => $request->balance,
            'check_or_slip' => $request->check_or_slip,
            'category' => $request->category,
            'property' => $request->property,
            'notes' => $request->notes
        ]);

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Purchase Order Created Successfully',
            'data' => new OrderResource($orders)
        ], 200);
    }
    //update database item
    public function update(Request $request, Orders $orders)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'details' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'posting_date' => 'string|max:255',
            'description' => 'string|max:255',
            'amount' => 'decimal:2',
            'type' => 'string|max:255',
            'balance' => 'decimal:2',
            'check_or_slip' => 'string|max:255',
            'category' => 'string|max:255',
            'property' => 'string|max:255',
            'notes' => 'string|max:255'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'All fields are mandatory',
                'error' => $validator->messages(),
            ], 422);
        }

        $orders->update([
            'details' => $request->details,
            'posting_date' => $request->posting_date,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'amount' => $request->amount,
            'type' => $request->type,
            'balance' => $request->balance,
            'check_or_slip' => $request->check_or_slip,
            'category' => $request->category,
            'property' => $request->property,
            'notes' => $request->notes
        ]);

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Purchase Order Updated Successfully',
            'data' => new OrderResource($orders)
        ], 200);
    }
    //get from database
    public function show(Orders $orders)
    {
        return new OrderResource($orders);
    }
    //delete from database
    public function destroy(Orders $orders)
    {
        $orders->delete();
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Purchase Order Deleted Successfully',
            'data' => new OrderResource($orders)
        ], 200);
    }
}

I have tried using the update and delete on a single order item http://localhost:8000/api/orders/3 which returns success but no changes in the database guessing because single items are returning null.
{
    "details" : "test",
    "posting_date" : "2024-09-04 04:21:38",
    "description" : "test",
    "amount" : "25.00",
    "type" : "test",
    "balance" : "55.00",
    "check_or_slip" : "test",
    "category" : "test",
    "property" : "test",
    "notes" : "test"
}

 GET|HEAD        / .................................................................................................................................................................................... 
  POST            api/login ................................................................................................................................................... Api\AuthController@login  
  POST            api/logout ................................................................................................................................................. Api\AuthController@logout  
  GET|HEAD        api/orders ......................................................................................................................... orders.index › Api\PurchaseOrdersController@index  
  POST            api/orders ......................................................................................................................... orders.store › Api\PurchaseOrdersController@store  
  GET|HEAD        api/orders/{order} ................................................................................................................... orders.show › Api\PurchaseOrdersController@show  
  PUT|PATCH       api/orders/{order} ............................................................................................................... orders.update › Api\PurchaseOrdersController@update  
  DELETE          api/orders/{order} ............................................................................................................. orders.destroy › Api\PurchaseOrdersController@destroy  
  GET|HEAD        api/profile ............................................................................................................................................... Api\AuthController@profile  
  POST            api/register ............................................................................................................................................. Api\AuthController@register  
  GET|HEAD        api/user .............................................................................................................................................................................  
  GET|HEAD        sanctum/csrf-cookie ................................................................................................ sanctum.csrf-cookie › Laravel\Sanctum › CsrfCookieController@show  
  GET|HEAD        up ................................................................................................................................................................................... 

result of DD in the show function
App\Models\Orders {#1188 // app\Http\Controllers\Api\PurchaseOrdersController.php:110
  #connection: null
  #table: "accounting"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  +usesUniqueIds: false
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: array:10 [
    0 => "details"
    1 => "posting_date"
    2 => "description"
    3 => "amount"
    4 => "type"
    5 => "balance"
    6 => "check_or_slip"
    7 => "category"
    8 => "property"
    9 => "notes"
  ]
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}


Can you add the result of dd of $orders for show method ?

I edited the post to show the results of dd as it's too long to add here

It seems to me that the response is showing empty original array. Please try doing $orders->toArray() and also check values in the database.

it comes out blank. When I do show for all results, all the data comes up. ex. http://localhost:8000/api/orders/ shows all results but http://localhost:8000/api/orders/1 shows null

if i run echo $orders->find(3); in the show function, it will output the correct data but after the return new OrderResource($orders) will return null

does your update route work? or only the show has the issue?

update route does not work either, however, the store route works and creates items and adds to database

Since you're doing implicit model binding, your type hinted variable has to match the URI parameter name. Based on your route definition:
api/orders/{order}

Your $orders variable in the show() method is not matching that, so model binding doesn't work here, and wont return any results.
Change your method definition to this:
public function show(Orders $order)
{
    return new OrderResource($order);
}

You can read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#implicit-binding

That seemed to work, thank you

the issue is on the naming of your route parameters while using a resource route. The route parameters are named in singular case "order".
You can verify this by: php artisan route:list --path=api/
To fix it you must rename your route parameters to match the expected names on the route definition, so: public function show(Orders $order)

This was it, thank you

Your show method should be like:
public function show(Orders $orders)
{
    return new OrderResource($orders[0]);
}

Or
public function show($id)
{
    return new OrderResource(Orders::find($id));
}

